# System performance issues when showing TortoiseSVN icons on network drives?

Tags: svn

In the TortoiseSVN FAQ [here](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#ovlonlylocal), there are instructions on how to turn on TortoiseSVN icons for network drives, and the performance reason for why this is not turned on by default.  In particular, the FAQ writer says:

> Be aware that enabling overlays for network drives will slow down not
>   only TortoiseSVN but the **whole system**.

I'm trying to quantify what the "whole system" slowdown really is.  Have any of you experienced this slowdown, and can you comment on it?  Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try to turn it on and see yourself? You always can turn it off back

Comment: I did... I couldn't detect any difference but I am concerned it may come up in certain I/O situations.  That's why I was wondering if anyone else had noticed anything.

Comment: I didn't too, to be clear ;-)

Comment: I will try some more & see if I can spot anything :-)